# Squeeze Theorem vs instantaneous rates of change

Tags: limits, derivatives

When we consider derivatives / instantaneous rates of change, what matters is determining the tangent line at a given point.

With squeeze theorem, we look at limits (an admittedly different concept) with the thought that it doesn't matter what is happening to a function at a given point, just *near* it.

Given that understanding, is it still possible to determine derivatives for continuous functions at a point where we must determine the limit via squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\sin$ function one may use $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ to find the limit at zero, and further $\cos(x)\le\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le 1$ to find its derivative at zero. Both proofs use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.